# Journal with good reputation on Dynamical Systems and Complex Dynamics

Tags: soft-question

I am wondering which journal are considered good to publish at in the areas of Dynamical Systems (Hamiltonian Dynamics) and Complex Dynamics.

I have a tendency to ignore completely the journal in which the papers I am reading were published (and in most cases I just get the arxiv copies) and I cannot really make sense of all the different ranking tables.

EDIT: I was not completely clear. I meant to ask about 2 separate categories:

- Dynamical Systems
- Complex Dynamics

I have a good result in Hamiltonian systems that I need to publish and I think I can get a good (related but separate) result in Complex Dynamics.

Comment: ETDS (Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems) is considered by many the top specialised journal in the field. Of course, like any matter of reputation, this can be debated, but I tend to agree. ETDS often publishes complex dynamics articles. Of course, good results in dynamical systems are also published in excellent general (rather than  specialised) mathematics journals, which exist at all levels of reputation. Ask your supervisor or colleagues about appropriate venues if you are not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Discrete and Continuous Dynamical Systems (A and B)

SIAM Applied Dynamical Systems

Journal of Nonlinear Science

Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems

Nonlinearity

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wanted also information about journals on Complex Dynamics. I edited the question.

Comment: DCDS and ETDS both often have papers in complex dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Physical Review E (https://journals.aps.org/pre/), or Physica D (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/01672789)? Both cover nonlinear phenomena and accept primarily mathematical papers . . .

They are also likely much more widely read and highly respected than most other journals publishing results in these themes.

I, too, dislike publishing in places where I myself find most other papers not interesting. That is a good index whether the publication is widely read.
So in that regard these two are high quality: just about *each* issue has relatively *many* interesting papers . . .

Yes, I would recommend publishing both types of papers, Dynamical Systems, and separately Complex Dynamics, in these journals. Send one paper to the first, and the other to the second, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I actually meant to ask separately also about Complex Dynamics. I edited the question.